# Pause VLC with batch file

Tags: vlc-media-player, filemaker

I have a database which contains file paths to .mp3 files in Filemaker. I managed to open these files in VLC with a Send Event command.

I also want to create a pause button, which has to tell VLC to pause. I don't know how to write a batch file to make VLC do this. I tried something like `vlc pause` and `vlc --pause`, but that doesn't work.

Can please anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably start at the Wiki for VLC. After a bit of glancing over this article it looks as if there is some pause functionality within the playlist. Have a look for yourself.

https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/

Comment: `vlc://pause:<seconds>`

This appears to be what you were looking for